# getting 403 error(Fullcontact Api key contains non-hex characters )

Tags: javascript, node.js, fullcontact

- Hi I am trying to update fullContact apiKey
- My new key is in this format -> `Wa**IuyqQZd****YhUiko**Asdc**POU`
- My old key is in this format ->  `aq******982ad**s`
- I am calling fullContact APi from Node Js

> ajax call :

```
var url = 'https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json';
var data ={email:'abc@gmail.com',apiKey:'Wa**IuyqQZd****YhUiko**Asdc**POU'};
request({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                useQuerystring: true,
                qs: data
            },

function(error, response, body) { 
       //handling response here
       if ((error || !response || response.statusCode > 400) && statusCode !== 404) {
            console.log('Request to FullContact failed (status `' + statusCode + '`, time `' + time + '`):', data, error, body);
                    resolve(null);
                    return;
                }

});
```

- But i am getting error after updating new key

> Request to FullContact failed (status `403`, time `1.467 sec`): {
>   email: 'abc@gmail.com',   apiKey: 'Wa##IuyqQZdyu##YhUiko##AsdcPOU' }
>   null { "status":403, "message":"Api key contains non-hex characters or
>   is otherwise invalid" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

> UPDATE

- Got the answer in the following way

---

```
request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        useQuerystring: true,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer "+data.apiKey
          },
        qs: data,

        }
```

> as per recent documentation this need to pass ("Authorization": "Bearer "+data.apiKey) in header.